# Deployment Issue Event Reciver

Tags: deployment, event-receivers

i built a event receiver it works 100%.  when i deploy it manually using power shell it deploys with no error

i then used Get-SPSolution to see if it has been deployed and it returns true

when i go to central admin or site collection features i cant find the solution to activate it, but when i browse share point using share point manager i find that it is already active but the event receiver is not being fired.
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following:-

1. At times due to way the event receivers are coded you may manually need to activate it through the "Manage Site Features" and not "Site Collection Features" in the top level site where the event receiver was deployed.
2. Check the status of its attached events using the [Event Receiver Tool](http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/02/29/tool-eventreceiver-installer-for-sharepoint/). A small utility that lets you browse through your sharepoint site libraries and lists and lets you see what features are attached to different events within the list/library.
3. If your event receiver deals with sending item level information to mapped table in a custom database , check the connectivity between the front end server and the database including the connection strings on your web config file.
4. Lastly do check your event logs (both Windows & ULS) , and see if service or timer jobs are failing. This can get you an insight on external causes if any.

Answer (score 0):

Two things and you're good to go:

Deactivate all features

Retract solution WSP

Deploy WSP again

perform an iisresets across all WFE